# std::ifstream file edited by another process

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

Is there a way to open a file in C++ and see only the context of the file from the state the file was in when it was opened (so if the file was modified while it was opened, the changes won't be visible)?
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define CHUNK 100000

int main()
{
    std::ifstream m_istr("a.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if(!m_istr.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "NOT OPENED!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    auto buffer = new uint8_t[CHUNK];
    system("@echo lol >> a.txt");

    m_istr.read((char*)buffer, CHUNK);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

I do not want to see the string `lol` appended to my `buffer`.
I can make an exclusive tmp copy file, open it and after I am done delete it, but I am wandering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: It might be beneficial if you add some context as to what you're trying to achieve/implement overall to avoid XY problems: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: That seems OS specific. I would kind of expect OS to prevent opening a file while another program has open file handle to that file...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Outside of IBM mainframes, that's pretty much Windows-only.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Comment: Thanks, guys.
I actually do not want to prevent the process to write to my open file, I just do not want to see new changes.
What I want: when requested, I want to show customer the content of some process's log file. I am reading content of the file in smaller chunks, so I do not want the last chunk to be updated with logs that happened after I opened the file. 
I should find the solution for both Win and Linux, but Win is my main focus now.
for example, Once I open a file using Notepad, the content is not changed no matter who is editing it in anthr process. That kind of snapshot I need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a cleaner solution. But it is OS specific.
For example, in Windows you can open file with exclusive access rights. Something like this:

```
For example: HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(lpszFileFullPathName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
```